# Can I create a nuget package without a project file

Tags: .net, nuget, octopus-deploy

We are trying to integrate Octopus-Deploy with our existing build process. Octopus-Deploy expects nuget packages to deploy. Now, for a variety of reasons, we change various file configurations after the build against the compiled files, so if we used the octopack tool, the packaging happens too early in our build process for us.

We will end up with a folder of e.g. mywebsite_QA and mywebsite_UAT, each containing the correct config files, etc, and it is thesefolders that we wish to deploy.

I would like to take these already built files, (mostly web applications) and turn them into nuget packages.

I am a bit of a noob with nuget, and I cannot see an easy way to do this, because it seems to require a project file or assembly.

**Is there some way to take a web site directory structure and turn it into a nuget package?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, see the Nuget pack documentation
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Pack_Command

Just run nuget.exe with the right options during your build process.

If you are using TeamCity, you can use it's Nuget package step.

Comment: OK thanks, I had to do two things: 1) create a nuspec file via nuget spec and then 2) pack with No analysis via "nuget pack -NoPackageAnalysis"